# ASP.NET Regular Expression Validator not validating as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I am trying to validate a phone number in the format `(###)###-####` with `\([0-9]{3}\)[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}` in visual studio using the regular expression validator. I am receiving the error message with (111)111-1111. Yet when I do this on a regex testing site it works fine. Is there something else at play here that I am missing?

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator
     ID="PhoneValidator"
     runat="server"
     ErrorMessage="Phone Format Must Be (###)###-####" 
     ValidationExpression="/\([0-9]{3}\)[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}/g"
     Display="None" 
     ControlToValidate="PhoneTextBox">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: Which site? Different regex engines have subtle differences.

Comment: I also notice that in your validator, you are using `/pattern/g`, which appears to be interpreted as part of the pattern instead of as a regex directive.

Answer (score 5):

If you look at the example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator.aspx), you'll see that in this context the regular expression should *not* start and end with `/` markers.  Try this instead:

```
ValidationExpression="^\([0-9]{3}\)[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$"
```

The `^` and `$` ensure you're not accepting extra characters before or after the phone number.

Answer (score 1):

You also want to consider extension too. For example, (770)123-4567 x1234.

```
((\(\d{3}\) ?)|(\d{3}-))?\d{3}-\d{4}( x\d{0,})?
```

[Validating Phone Numbers with Extensions in ASP.NET](http://odetocode.com/articles/265.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I was actually having a problem elsewhere on the page sending a blank textbox of a date. Apparently C# interpreted the empty field as `01/01/0001` and therefore made it out of range. This was throwing everything else off. @neontapir You are right; I should not have had those on the expression. I didn't originally but just so happens I did when I posted this. Thanks.